How does arctime in Metapost work?
Please look at the following Metapost code:
path p;
p = (0,0){up}..{right}(200,100)..{up}(300,400)..cycle;
len := arclength p;
s := arctime (2500) of p;
t := arctime (len+2500) of p;
draw p;
show len;% 2799
show s;% 2.92...
show t;% 2.67...

Why are s and t not the same? When I add an arclength nothing should change, I think. Where is the mistake?
Edit: I used Version 2.02 from here:
http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/
This is MetaPost, version 2.02 (TeX Live 2023) (kpathsea version 6.3.5)  28 APR 2024 02:47
 **preview.mp
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
 Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./preview.mp
 >> 2799.0210591829564
 >> 2.9211035593209118
 >> 2.6795082428530486 [0] )
 1 output file written: preview.mps


I do not see why it should not work. Maybe numerics due to weird path (with a circle it worked here). Maybe it helps to do t := arctime ((len + 2500) mod len) of p ;?

Yes, for a fullcircle I get almost the same values. Not exactly, but OK.

It's not a rounding error: I tried with -numbersystem=double and the figures are len=2799.0210591829564, s=2.9211035593209118 and t=2.6795082428530486.

I don't see any reason adding an arclength should remain the same behavior, nothing in the documentation I can find that says arctime is done modulo. Reasonably, I'd expect that arctime(1) use the Bezier control point of the first Bezier segment, while arctime(arclength+1) uses that of the last Bezier segment, and the value after the endpoint is merely extrapolation based on plugging numbers in the formula that just happens to be smooth.

I got t= 5.92111 on version 2.10, using the default -numbersystem=scale

With Version 2.00 I get t=5.92..., too. Looks like a bug.

@WeißerKater  Which version of mpost were you using originally?  Can you post the log file?

With the current version I get ```This is MetaPost, version 2.10 (TeX Live 2024) (kpathsea version 6.4.0)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp


2799.02077
2.92111
5.92111 [1] )
1 output file written: b.1
Transcript written on b.log.
```  which looks entirely correct, since arctime arclength p of p == length p (which is 3 in this case).



@Thruston: See edit.

The differences likely depend on the numbersystem you use, as indicated by @LdBeth. To give an argument that it is in the accuracy: Try to first do p := p scaled .5 and then do the calculation. The double mode is often still using/depending on scaled internally.

I do not claim fully understand what arctime does and the algorithm used to calculate it. Checking MetaPost source code, in the mp.w file (you can try compile this CWEB file to PDF using cweave, but some _s are not prefixed with \_ which causes error when TeXed), section 405, "The arclength and arctime operations are both based on a recursive function that finds the arc length of a cubic spline given dz0, dz1, dz2..." and the actual implementation is the mp_get_arc_time function in section 419.
By reading these sections, what I have understood is arctime is implemented by zero finding, using binary search on float (or fixed point) number, to implement the inverse function of mp_do_arc_test().
If using MetaPost in command line with default 32-bit fixed point (aka scaled), epsilon = 0.00002.
The http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/ uses double, which sets epsilon = 1.52587890625e-05, and other number systems all uses similar values.
The section 419 says,

If arc0 is greater than the arc length of a cyclic path h, the result is a time value greater than the length of the path.

where arc0 is the numeric argument provided to arctime.
Using a modified example from the question,
path p;
p = (0,0){up}..{right}(200,100)..{up}(300,400)..cycle;
len := arclength p;
s := arctime (2500) of p;
t := arctime (len+2500) of p;
show len;
show s;
show t;
show epsilon;
show arclength subpath (0,t) of p;
show len+2500;
end;

Using default scaled number system:
>> 2799.02077
>> 2.92111
>> 5.92111
>> 0.00002
>> 5299.043
>> 5299.02077

using -numbersystem=double
>> 2799.0210591829564
>> 2.9211035593209118
>> 2.6795082428530486
>> 1.52587890625e-05
>> 2200.7155501530865
>> 5299.0210591829564

It seems to me that the t=5.92 is the correct value that fits this description, and the result can be interpreted using t = s + l, where l is the length of the cyclic path p, which is length 3. And in addition it fits the MetaPost Manual description on the behavior of arctime which says arclength subpath (0,t) of p = a
So it is very likely the t=2.67... result indicates a bug due to the added different number systems.

"(you can try compile this CWEB file to PDF using cweave, but some _s are not prefixed with _ which causes error when TeXed),"  -- you should find that these have all been fixed in the latest commit to the dev system.

Further update: the dev team have posted a fix to the repository.   I pulled it from there and built it locally and it looks good.  Using the example as pasted below, I now get this:
> mpost b.mp
This is MetaPost, version 2.11 (TeX Live 2025/dev) (kpathsea version 6.4.0/dev)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp
>> 2799.02077
>> 2.92111
>> 5.92111
>> 3
>> "scaled" [1] )
1 output file written: b.1
Transcript written on b.log.

> mpost -numbersystem=double b.mp
This is MetaPost, version 2.11 (TeX Live 2025/dev) (kpathsea version 6.4.0/dev)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp
>> 2799.0210591829564
>> 2.9211035593209118
>> 5.9211035593209118
>> 3
>> "double" [1] )
1 output file written: b.1
Transcript written on b.log.

and similar from the other number systems.  This fix will no doubt work its way into the standard distributions in due course.
Answering the original question
The arctime operator in MP returns the time t on a path when arclength of the path gets to a desired length in PostScript points.
So if p is a path, and a is the desired length, then arctime a of p gives the time t such that arclength subpath(0, t) of p = a.  In all normal usage you should make sure that the desired length a is between 0 and arclength p.
But if the path p happens to be cyclic, then you can give a longer length.   This is similar to the way that you can refer to point 9 of fullcircle etc.   If you examine the source code, you will see that MP specifically provides for the desired length to be longer that the actual length of a cyclic path.  The algorithm works along the path point by point and if it gets back to the beginning of a cycle it does a calculation to short cut the rest of the process (if you really want the details you can examine the source code).
The implementation of this calculation caused a bug with the new number systems and that has now been corrected.  Kudos to the development team for a speedy fix.

Update: the development team confirm that this looks like a bug due to the use of implicit integer maths in the MP source code.

This is really a comment, but the log file sections are too long, so I am answering this.
With the current version of MP, I find that your example gives expected results with the old scaled number system.  But "unexpected" results with any of the three new systems.  This looks like something to report to the development team.
If I add a couple of lines to the OP example, like so:
beginfig(1);
path p;
p = (0,0){up}..{right}(200,100)..{up}(300,400)..cycle;
len := arclength p;
s := arctime (2500) of p;
t := arctime (len+2500) of p;
draw p;
show len;% 2799
show s;% 2.92...
show t;% 2.67...
show arctime arclength p of p;
show numbersystem;

endfig;
end

Then I get this log file if I run with mpost using the default number system:
This is MetaPost, version 2.10 (TeX Live 2024) (kpathsea version 6.4.0)  28 APR 2024 15:56
**b.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp
>> 2799.02077
>> 2.92111
>> 5.92111
>> 3
>> "scaled" [1] )
1 output file written: b.1

But if I use any of the other three number systems, I get the "unexpected" value of t first reported.  So apparently something goes wrong in computing the arclength of a cyclic path using the new number systems.
:!mpost -numbersystem=double b.mp
This is MetaPost, version 2.10 (TeX Live 2024) (kpathsea version 6.4.0)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp
>> 2799.0210591829564
>> 2.9211035593209118
>> 2.6795082428530486
>> 3
>> "double" [1] )
1 output file written: b.1
Transcript written on b.log.
"b.log" 12L, 389B    

:!mpost -numbersystem=decimal b.mp
This is MetaPost, version 2.10 (TeX Live 2024) (kpathsea version 6.4.0)  28 APR 2024 15:58
**b.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp
>> 2799.021059182955437254465959453077
>> 2.921103559320912153438877894997069
>> 2.67950824285304864431956913069307
>> 3
>> "decimal" [1] )
1 output file written: b.1

:!mpost -numbersystem=binary b.mp
This is MetaPost, version 2.10 (TeX Live 2024) (kpathsea version 6.4.0)  28 APR 2024 15:58
**b.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./b.mp
>> 2799.0210591829554372544659594531163
>> 2.9211035593209121534388778949970568
>> 2.6795082428530486443195691306930351
>> 3
>> "binary" [1] )
1 output file written: b.1

In my experience with MP, the old scaled system is almost always better.  The OP might like to ask the owner of the previewer at thiv.org to use the default number system unless specifically requested otherwise.

I have pinged an email about this to the MP discussion group:  https://tug.org/pipermail/metapost/
